# AttributeError: 'Map' object has no attribute 'tiles' tkinter python 3.9

Tags: python, class, object, tkinter, attributes

I have Map class which is as below:

```
class Map:
def _init_(self):
    self.tiles = [
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
        [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]]
def is_floor(self, x, y):
    return self.tiles[y][x] == 0
```

and main file is as below:

```
from tkinter import *
from Hero import Hero
from map import Map

IMG_SIZE = 72
WIDTH = 10 * IMG_SIZE
HEIGHT = 10 * IMG_SIZE

root = Tk()
root.title('Wanderer Game')
canvas = Canvas(root, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT)
canvas.pack()

hero = Hero()
game_map = Map()

def draw_screen():
    canvas.delete("all")
    for i in range(len(game_map.tiles)): # error on here
        for j in range(len(game_map.tiles[i])):
            if game_map.tiles[i][j] == 0:
                image = root.floor
            else:
                image = root.wall
            canvas.create_image(j * 72, i * 72, anchor=NW, image=image)
```

Running the above code generates an error:

> AttributeError: 'Map' object has no attribute 'tiles'

the code is actually running perfectly on other system so I was wondering if the python version is causing the error, I am new to python and tkinter library so would appreciate any help

Comment: where exactly is the error? at the first reference of `.tiles`?

Comment: btw it is `__init__` not `_init_` which actually seems to be the issue

Comment: yes it solved my problem, thanks alot